# Dos datos en una misma columna de una tupla

Tags: mysql

Estoy diseñando la db en mysql para un instituto de inglés y quiero asignar que un curso tenga uno o más días que se dicta.
Ejemplo: Avanzado Adultos se dicta Martes y Jueves.

```
CREATE TABLE dias (
    idDia INT(1) NOT NULL,
    dia VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idDia)
);

INSERT INTO dias VALUES
    (1, 'Lunes'),
    (2, 'Martes'),
    (3, 'Miércoles'),
    (4, 'Jueves'),
    (5, 'Viernes'),
    (6, 'Sábado');

CREATE TABLE cursos (
    idCurso INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    dias INT(1) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_dias FOREIGN KEY(dias) REFERENCES dias(idDia),
    horario TIME NOT NULL,
    anio INT(4) NOT NULL,
    nivel VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idCurso)
);
```

Sé cómo insertar un dato en una columna
`INSERT INTO cursos VALUES (1, 'Avanzado Adultos', 2, 203000, 2023, 'B1');`
pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo con dos (dias), sin hacer otro insert con el mismo idCurso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que la situación que estás planteando es un relación de `varios a varios` (un curso puede estar en varios días, así como un día puede tener varios cursos), lo mejor que podrías hacer es crear una entidad intermedia.

Con esto, respetás la propiedad de unicidad de los atributos.

Esta entidad relacionaría los días con los cursos y acá te dejo el código completo de cómo sería con estos cambios.

```
CREATE TABLE dias (
    idDia INT NOT NULL,
    dia VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idDia)
);

CREATE TABLE cursos (
    idCurso INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    horario TIME NOT NULL,
    anio INT NOT NULL,
    nivel VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idCurso)
);
```

De la tabla cursos, eliminé la columna dias.

La tabla intermediaria:

```
CREATE TABLE cursosdias (
    idDia INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_idDia FOREIGN KEY(idDia) REFERENCES dias(idDia),
    idCurso INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT idCurso FOREIGN KEY(idCurso) REFERENCES cursos(idCurso)
);
```

Entonces, ya habiendo cargado cargado los datos de dias y cursos, hacés un `INSERT INTO cursosdias VALUES(idDia, idCurso)` y cuando los consultes, vas a poder recibir los datos correspondientes.

Ejemplo de inserción de los datos:

```
INSERT INTO cursosdias VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 1), (5, 2)
```

Ejemplo de rescate de los datos:

```
SELECT C.nombre, C.horario, C.anio, C.nivel, D.dia
FROM cursos C, dias D, cursosdias E
WHERE C.idCurso = E.idCurso && D.idDia = E.idDia
```

Lo que me devuelve (según los datos que yo cargué):

| nombre | horario | anio | nivel | dia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ninios | 17:30:00 | 2023 | B1 | Lunes |
| Ninios | 17:30:00 | 2023 | B1 | Miercoles |
| Adultos | 20:00:00 | 2023 | B1 | Lunes |
| Adultos | 20:00:00 | 2023 | B1 | Miercoles |

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Pero en la tabla `cursosdias` falta una restricción del tipo `UNIQUE`  o `PRIMARY KEY` compuesta por las columnas `(idDia, idCurso)`. Tal y como está definida la tabla ahora, algo como esto es posible: `INSERT INTO cursosdias VALUES (1,1), (1,1), (1,1), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2);` resultando, como es evidente, en redundancia de datos que provocarán resultados disparatados en muchos escenarios.

Comment: Debería tener ambos como PK entonces? No podría ser UNIQUE, ya que justamente necesito que los valores se repitan, no?